# Add click event on each category name on X axis in c3 js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, graph, c3.js

I'm using c3 js for generating categories bar chart

Here is code

```
      var obj = {
                size: {
                    height: 200,
                },
                bindto: '#grBarChart',
                data: {
                    columns: data.columns,
                    type: "bar"
                },
                color: {
                    pattern: ['#c90000', '#008cba', '#FAAC3D','#427322', '#9ead9b', '#ffa500']
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'category',
                        categories: data.categories,
                        label: {
                            text: 'Scanned Groups',
                            position: 'outer-center'
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        label: {
                            text: 'Count (Rules)',
                            position: 'outer-middle'
                        }
                    }
                },
                bar: {
                    width: {
                        ratio: 0.5,
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    y: {
                        show: true
                    }
                }
            };
            var chart = c3.generate(obj);
```

This code is generating the following graph 
[image]

Now my problem is I'm not able to add click event on X Axis Category Names ( Logging 11, Data Protection 13 ...)

I referred  [C3 Documentation](https://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-label) but not able to solve my problem.

Please give me your thought?

Comment: Have you identified class applied to category names and bind click event handlers? can you recreate this on jsfiddle?